# Access BaseController property from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a property in my BaseModel to keep track of the current user, like this:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public UserModel currentUser;

        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
            currentUser = userRep.getCurrentUser();
        }
    }
```

How can I access that variable in my Models, or is there a way of creating something similar in the `BaseModel` ?

Comment: create object for the baseController in model

Comment: Why would you need this?  Are you not using traditional authentication methods that would put the user in the User property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give **namespace** in view like below:

```
@using TestMVCApp.Controllers
@{
     var currentUser = BaseController.currentUser;
}
```

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public static UserModel currentUser;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        currentUser.id = 5;
    }

}
```

Comment: You must never store session specific data into a static member ! This value would be **unique** for all your users within your hosting process (application domain). When accessing your application concurrently by multiple users, result will be... unpredictable.